# Apache & Nginx in Same Directory

Tags: apache, nginx, directory, document, root

I want to use Apache and Nginx in the same directory:

```
nginx root /home/admin/tv;

Apache DocumentRoot domain root /home/admin/tv;
```

I set the same directory but when I go to the Nginx addreess

```
ip:777 i got  403 Forbidden nginx/0.8.54
```

I finally change the permission and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't run one of each. They just have to bind to different sockets. The 403 error is because you configured permissions incorrectly.

Comment: how i change the permission of the folder /home/admin?

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with this earlier, I have apache and nginx and testing both on my server. you should be able to use the same directory with existing sites as long as you make the changes in your virutal host of both to reflect you chosen directory. I don't think you can run both at the same time though.